# How to convert a Mono<Map<String, Optional<String>>> to a Flux<Tuple<String, Optional<String>>>

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm using WebFlux with Reactor and creating a rest service that aggregates and transforms results from an internal service call using WebFlux webclient.

The client returns a `Mono<Map<String, Optional<String>>>`
which I want to disassemble in a Flux with key, value elements so that I can combine it later on.

I was thinking of converting the client response of type

`Mono<Map<String, Optional<String>>>` to a

`Flux<Tuple<String, String>>`

I know you can convert a `Mono<List<String>>` to a  `Flux<String>` using `responseMono.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)`

but I couldn't find a way to handle Maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mono.flatMapMany(map -> Flux.fromIterable(map.entrySet()))` which will give you a `Flux<Entry<String, Optional<String>>>`.

If you explicitly want it to be a `Tuple`, not an `Entry`, then just do:

```
mono.flatMapMany(map -> Flux.fromIterable(map.entrySet()))
        .map(e -> Tuples.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```